# Optim.jl univariate bounded optimization confusing output when using Inf as bound

Tags: optimization, julia, numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization

The following is a self-contained example illustrating my problem.

```
using Optim

χI = 3
ψI = 0.5
ϕI(z) = z^-ψI
λ = 1.0532733
V0 = 0.8522423425
zE = 0.5986

wRD = 0.72166623555


objective1(z) = -(z * χI * ϕI(z + zE)  *  (λ-1) * V0 - z * ( wRD ))
objective2(z) = -1 * objective1(z)

lower = 0.01
upper = Inf

plot(0:0.01:0.1,objective1,title = "objective1")
png("/home/nico/Desktop/objective1.png")
plot(0:0.01:0.1,objective2, title = "objective2")
png("/home/nico/Desktop/objective2.png")

results1 = optimize(objective1,lower,upper)
results2 = optimize(objective2,lower,upper)
```

The plots are

[image: Plot of objective1(z)]

and

[image: Plot of objective2(z)]

Both `objective1(z)` and `objective2(z)` return `NaN` at `z = 0` and finite values everywhere else, with an optimum for some `z > 0`.

However the output of `results1` is

```
Results of Optimization Algorithm
 * Algorithm: Brent's Method
 * Search Interval: [0.010000, Inf]
 * Minimizer: Inf
 * Minimum: NaN
 * Iterations: 1000
 * Convergence: max(|x - x_upper|, |x - x_lower|) <= 2*(1.5e-08*|x|+2.2e-16): false
 * Objective Function Calls: 1001
```

and the output of `results2` is

```
Results of Optimization Algorithm
 * Algorithm: Brent's Method
 * Search Interval: [0.010000, Inf]
 * Minimizer: Inf
 * Minimum: NaN
 * Iterations: 1000
 * Convergence: max(|x - x_upper|, |x - x_lower|) <= 2*(1.5e-08*|x|+2.2e-16): false
 * Objective Function Calls: 1001
```

I believe the problem is with `upper = Inf`. If I change that to `upper = 100`, for example, the output of `results1` is

```
Results of Optimization Algorithm
 * Algorithm: Brent's Method
 * Search Interval: [0.010000, 100.000000]
 * Minimizer: 1.000000e-02
 * Minimum: 5.470728e-03
 * Iterations: 55
 * Convergence: max(|x - x_upper|, |x - x_lower|) <= 2*(1.5e-08*|x|+2.2e-16): true
 * Objective Function Calls: 56
```

and `results2` returns

```
Results of Optimization Algorithm
 * Algorithm: Brent's Method
 * Search Interval: [0.010000, 100.000000]
 * Minimizer: 1.000000e+02
 * Minimum: -7.080863e+01
 * Iterations: 36
 * Convergence: max(|x - x_upper|, |x - x_lower|) <= 2*(1.5e-08*|x|+2.2e-16): true
 * Objective Function Calls: 37
```

as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you note in your question - you use *bounded optimization* algorithm but you pass an unbounded interval to it.

Citing the documentation (https://julianlsolvers.github.io/Optim.jl/latest/#user/minimization/), which is precise about it the `optimize` function is for *Minimizing a univariate function on a bounded interval*.

To give a more detail about the problem you encounter. The `optimize` method searches points inside your interval. There are two algorithms implemented: Brent (the default) and Golden Section. The point they first check is:

```
new_minimizer = x_lower + golden_ratio*(x_upper-x_lower)
```

and you see that it `new_minimizer` will be `Inf`. So the optimization routine is not even able to find a valid interior point. Then you see that your functions return `NaN` for `Inf` argument:

```
julia> objective1(Inf)
NaN

julia> objective2(Inf)
NaN
```

This combined gives you explanation why the minimum found is `Inf` and the objective is `NaN` in the produced output.

The second point is that you should remember that `Float64` numbers have a finite precision, so you should choose the interval so as to make sure that the method is actually able to accurately evaluate the objective in it. For example even this fails:

```
julia> optimize(objective1, 0.0001, 1.0e308)
Results of Optimization Algorithm
 * Algorithm: Brent's Method
 * Search Interval: [0.000100, 100000000000000001097906362944045541740492309677311846336810682903157585404911491537163328978494688899061249669721172515611590283743140088328307009198146046031271664502933027185697489699588559043338384466165001178426897626212945177628091195786707458122783970171784415105291802893207873272974885715430223118336.000000]
 * Minimizer: 1.000005e+308
 * Minimum: -Inf
 * Iterations: 1000
 * Convergence: max(|x - x_upper|, |x - x_lower|) <= 2*(1.5e-08*|x|+2.2e-16): false
 * Objective Function Calls: 1001
```

The reason is that `objective1` actually starts to behave in a numerically unstable way for very large arguments (because it has a finite precision), see:

```
julia> objective1(1.0e307)
7.2166623555e306

julia> objective1(1.0e308)
-Inf
```

The last point is that actually `Optimize` tells you that something went wrong and you should not rely on the results as:

```
julia> results1.converged
false

julia> results2.converged
false
```

For the initial specification of the problem (with `Inf`).